# IntelliJ IDEA Reformat code and Rename exception?

Tags: intellij-idea

1. When `Reformat code` , the code format will change in an instant (no problem), but the font color of the code will change slowly. Sometimes a variable name has two colors.
2. About `Refactor - Rename`:

For example, I want to change the `oldVariableName` variable Rename to `newVariableName`. Sometimes it will be named as a confused `neardwVariableName`.

Moreover, sometimes when you click `Rename` for a variable, the pop-up window for modifying the name shows that the variable to be modified is another variable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: regarding 1: which version of IDEA do you use? which OS? what is your PC/laptop config? regarding 2: I believe this is a know issue in IDEA, but better open a ticket here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a code sample

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2 (Ultimate Edition), CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.60 GHz , RAM: 16.0 GB , Windows 11 22H2